# Autodesk Forge "Failed to trigger translation for this file" (Fusiondoc/F2D)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I can succesfully translate Fusion 360 designs (F3D) using the autodesk derivative api using the urn of the item version. But whenever I try to translate a Fusion 360 drawing (fusiondoc) I get a Bad Request error (400) with the following error message:

Error calling Translate: {"diagnostic":"Failed to trigger translation for this file."}

When i try to open the drawing on thr web using A360 and open it in the web viewer, it will succesfully prepare the file for viewing (takes a while), after which I can also view the translated file sucessfully from my own viewer re-using the same urn.

Does anyone have any experience translating fusion 360 drawings to svf using the derivative api for viewing?

Comment: If it doesn't contain any sensitive data, could you share the drawing and send it to forge [dot] help [at] autodesk [dot] com?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *fusiondoc* is supported by the Forge Model Derivative API. Please see the list of supported input/output file formats at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations.